# How to increase the background size automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]How to increase a background size  automatically when a new item is added to its page dynamically.

```
#container1 {
    background-image: url(wallpapers.jpg);
    height: auto;
}
#mid {
    background-image: url(scripts/white.png);
    width: 950px;
    margin-left: 210px;
    height: 1700px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container1">
    <div id="mid">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

I am unable to increase the background size beyond the height it defines even if I define it as auto not able to increase the size automatically when a new item is added.

please help I am in a need of it for my college project.

Thanks in advance waiting for your replies.

Comment: Simple, Do not specify the height of that div. Content will go and height will increase itself. Regards

Comment: i have added the snapshot
even agter setting height auto and background size to 100% its still d same

Comment: Well, you didnt mention you have content after that div too. Its called overflow property. By the way, you found the solution. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div #container takes up the height of its child element, i.e, #mid, which in this case has a height of 1700px. Thus your content is overflowing from that div element(#mid). 
You can either remove the height property from #mid, or have an `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use background-size property. It might be help you.

```
#container1 {
    background-image: url(wallpapers.jpg);
    height: auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a div if not styled to have definite height and width will grow and shrink according to the elements within the div.

Answer (score 0):

add `background-size: auto 100%;`  this value to `#container1` div in css